# Not able to install mod_perl in freeswitch 1.6.5

Tags: freeswitch

Freeswitch is installed and working as it should. Now i want to install perl module(mod_perl) for that i have uncomment the line

```
'languages/mod_perl' in freeswitch/modules.conf
```

and in uncomment the line

```
'<load module="mod_perl"/>' in /usr/local/freeswitch/conf/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml
```

and i am trying this but getting this error,

```
make mod_perl-install
Error:: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.22.1/x86_64-linux/CORE/libperl.a(op.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `PL_memory_wrap' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

I have tried to recompile with '-fPIC' as suggested by the system with these different ways, but without any success,

```
./configure CONFIGURE_CFLAGS=-fPIC
./configure CONFIGURE_CFLAGS=-fPIC --with-pic
./configure --disable-file --without-pic --disable-shared
```

Even change the variable in Makefile

```
from CXXFLAGS = -g -O2
to CXXFLAGS = -fPIC
```

Yet not able to install mod_perl in Freeswitch 1.6.5.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Devang

=============
Okay, got the solution::

Somehow perl's latest version 5.22.1 is not going well with Freeswitch 1.6.5
so i used 5.20.2 and after that try to install mod_perl and i got success.
Thanks though.

Comment: Just as a hint, which may simplify issues like this: the people developing FreeSwitch provide a [repository](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Debian+8+Jessie#Debian8Jessie-InstallingfromDebianpackages). Using this, you wouldn't have to compile the modules etc. yourself, but instead using `apt-get install ...` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

solution to your problem is:

- install the perl with thread option.